# Using self-defined data transform function in Spark Structured Stream

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, data-transform

I read the following blog and find the API is very useful.

https://databricks.com/blog/2017/02/23/working-complex-data-formats-structured-streaming-apache-spark-2-1.html

In the blog, there are lots of data selection example. Like using input

```
{
  "a": {
     "b": 1
  }
}
```

Apply `Scala: events.select("a.b")`, the output would be

```
{
  "b": 1
}
```

But data type conversion are not mentioned in the blog. Saying I have the following input:

```
{
  "timestampInSec": "1514917353",
  "ip": "123.39.76.112",
  "money": "USD256",
  "countInString": "6"
}
```

The expected output is:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-01-02 11:22:33",
  "ip_long": 2066173040,
  "currency": "USD",
  "money_amount": 256,
  "count": 6
}
```

There are some transformations that not included in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`:

- Timestamp is in second and is a string type
- Convert IP to long
- Split `USD256` to two columns and convert one of the column to number
- Convert string to number

Another thing is error handling and default value. If there is an invalid input like:

```
{
  "timestampInSec": "N/A",
  "money": "999",
  "countInString": "Number-Six"
}
```

It is expected that the output can be

```
{
  "timestamp": "1970-01-01 00:00:00",
  "ip_long": 0,
  "currency": "NA",
  "money_amount": 999,
  "count": -1
}
```

- input `timestampInSec` is **not a number**. It is expected to use 0 and create a timestamp string as return value
- `ip` is **missing** in the input. It is expected to usea default value 0.
- `money` field is **not complete**. It has money amount but missed currency. It is expected to use `NA` as default currency and correctly translate the `money_amount`
- `countInString` is not a number. It is expected to use `-1` (**not 0**) as default value .

These requirments are not common and need some self-defined business logic code.

I do checked some function like `to_timestamp`. There are some codegen stuff and seems not very easy to add new functions. Is there some guide/document about writing self-defined transformation function? Is there a easy way to meet the requirments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

- > Timestamp is in second and is a string type

  ```scala
  val timestamp = coalesce(
     $"timestampInSec".cast("long").cast("timestamp"), 
     lit(0).cast("timestamp")
  ).alias("timestamp")
  ```
- > Split USD256 to two columns and convert one of the column to number

  ```scala
  val currencyPattern = "^([A-Z]+)?([0-9]+)$"

  val currency = (trim(regexp_extract($"money", currencyPattern, 1)) match {
    case c => when(length(c) === 0, "NA").otherwise(c)
  }).alias("currency")
  val amount = regexp_extract($"money", currencyPattern, 2)
    .cast("decimal(38, 0)").alias("money_amount")
  ```
- > Convert string to number

  ```scala
  val count = coalesce($"countInString".cast("long"), lit(-1)).alias("count")
  ```
- > Convert IP to long

  ```scala
  val ipPattern = "^([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})"
  val ip_long = coalesce(Seq((1, 24), (2, 16), (3, 8), (4, 0)).map {
    case (group, numBits) => shiftLeft(
      regexp_extract($"ip", ipPattern, group).cast("long"),
      numBits
    )
  }.reduce(_ + _), lit(0)).alias("ip_long")
  ```

Result

```scala
val df = Seq(
  ("1514917353", "123.39.76.112", "USD256", "6"),
  ("N/A", null, "999", null)
).toDF("timestampInSec", "ip", "money", "countInString")

df.select(timestamp, currency, amount, count, ip_long).show
// +-------------------+--------+------------+-----+----------+
// |          timestamp|currency|money_amount|count|   ip_long|
// +-------------------+--------+------------+-----+----------+
// |2018-01-02 18:22:33|     USD|         256|    6|2066173040|
// |1970-01-01 00:00:00|      NA|         999|   -1|         0|
// +-------------------+--------+------------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: As a greenhorn of sacla and spark, I have to say this is AMAZING!